# "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format" error in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, compiler-errors, double, visual-studio-2019

hello guys this is my code:

```
        double[] milad = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < milad.Length; i++)
        milad[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

but when I input a float number like 25.5 compiler error me "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format"
can somebody help me?

Comment: Code just works fine with me. Can you maybe add the screenshot of error? and your code

Comment: You are maybe typing `,` instead of `.` which is normal. You should somehow make to accept both `,` and `.`. What you can do is before parsing replace `,` with `.` in input string.

Comment: Such things are precisely why it is better to use `.TryParse` when working with user input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs without errors, it may be that your input is incorrect.

Do not use `','` instead of `'.'` .

**That's my Output:**

[image]

**Add your error in the comment below me, and I will give you suggestions.**

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I think the problem is the Visual Studio Compiler, not my code because I did what you say and even more but it didn't work. Even some of my friends said we did exact your code but we didn't get any error

Comment: I am also using Visual Studio 2019. If you think it is a problem with the Compiler, please reinstall it. If you do not give any further problem analysis, we will not be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok I think you right , and I'm gonna do that

Comment: Have you fixed the issue?

Comment: If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.